# Center vertically a unknown height text in a unknown height div

Tags: css, html, center

I know this is a common issue, and I've already asked a similar one.
But I could not find the solution this time.
I am trying to vertically center a text which can have different height in a DIV which can have different height.
And I am trying to solve this only with CSS, without touching the HTML.

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/F8TtE/

```
 <div id="test">
    <div id="sumup">

        <h1 class="titre">Title</h1>
        <div id="date">hello guys</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

My goal is to have the text centered vertically and horizontally whatever its size.

Comment: similar issue with solution can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788670/cant-vertically-alignmiddle-absolutely-positioned-block-text#19789090)

Comment: Here is an awesome reference -- http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/ . This solution is using the `:before` CSS "*pseudo-element*".

Comment: @Mahmoud The linked Q/A hardly answers this question : *"without touching the HTML"* and *"whatever its size"*

Comment: You've an extra `</div>` in there.. is it intentional..?

Comment: Sorry Denys ! It's ok now :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here it is :

```
#test {
    text-align:center;
}
#test::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#sumup {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
#test {
    height : 180px;
    text-align:center;
    background: yellow;
}

#sumup {
    background-color: #123456;
}

#test:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  #sumup {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="sumup">
   
   <h1 class="titre">Title</h1>
   <div id="date">hello guys</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT:** It's now 2015 and thankfully the web changes. Assuming you don't support [obsolete browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex), it's usually simpler and cleaner to vertically center elements with [the Flex model](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```
#test {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
#test {
    height : 180px;
    background: yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#sumup {
    background-color: #123456;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="sumup">
   <h1 class="titre">Title</h1>
   <div id="date">hello guys</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've used the table/table-cell method for a while now, but this... this is just magic.

Comment: Every answer on the web does this. The OP said "in a DIV which can have different height", meaning the height of the parent div can't be a set measurement.

Comment: With percentage height on the parent element this do not work. Anyone know another way?

Comment: This is the proper solution. I have been searching for quite a while but this is perfect.

Comment: In reference to the 2015 edit, I think most developers still want to support IE 9 and 10, [flex](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) complicates things a bit.

Comment: can anyone explain why this works? I'm so curious :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way using `display:table-cell` since I don't quite understand how dystroy's answer works.

```
#test {
    width:100%;
    height : 400px;
    display:table;
}

#sumup {
    width : 100%;

    height : 100%;
    background-color: #123456;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F8TtE/3/

Answer (score 0):

CSS with `display` solution:

```
#test {
  display:table; 
}

#sumup {
  display:table-cell; 
}
```

The Demo **http://jsfiddle.net/F8TtE/7/**