# Vertically center align divs with unknown height

Tags: css

I'm trying to solve a `vertical-align` problem involving the floating divs. All the heights are unknown - because they are implicitly formed only with the inside text lines.

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/zjzyryae/

```css
#test {
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
#block1 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
}
#block2 {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="block1">
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
  <div id="block2">
    sample
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to vertically center the "block2" div - with CSS only of course (no JavaScript).

See that "block1" div sets implicitly the parent "test" block height -  which makes the principal difference with the similar described cases (where this height is explicitly set in pixels).

Perhaps this question is solved somewhere but I haven't found exactly the same case. The similar examples I considered were different.

This one [Center vertically a unknown height text in a unknown height div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791120/center-vertically-a-unknown-height-text-in-a-unknown-height-div) actually includes the hard-coded height setting - which is dramatically different case than mine.

That one [How to vertically middle-align floating elements of unknown heights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557897/how-to-vertically-middle-align-floating-elements-of-unknown-heights) is also different case and not suitable for my situation - because the parent height is equal to the floating divs height (which is much easier than my case).

I tried to play with different `display:table` settings - but still no luck.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest to use flexbox, perfectly with `display: inline-flex` so it has the "shrink to fit" feature just like other inline level elements. And `align-items: center` makes all the flex items to align to the middle.

```css
#test {
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
#block1 {
  background-color: grey;
}
#block2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="block1">
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
  <div id="block2">
    sample
  </div>
</div>
```

If you do need to support older browsers, you can still use inline block (no float), the key is to set `vertical-align: middle`, and remove the [unwanted white space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/483779) if needed.

```css
#test {
  font-size: 0; /*remove white space*/
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
#block1,
#block2 {
  font-size: 16px; /*reset font size*/
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#block1 {
  background-color: grey;
}
#block2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="block1">
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
  <div id="block2">
    sample
  </div>
</div>
```

Or use CSS table, again set `vertical-align: middle`, but it works differently from inline blocks, it vertically centers the content or elements inside rather the element itself or siblings. I added a `<span>` tag for the background color.

```css
#test {
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#block1,
#block2 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#block1 {
  background-color: grey;
}
/* #block2 {
  background-color: green;
} */
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="block1">
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
  <div id="block2">
    <span style="background:green;">sample</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What an elegant solution. Looks like I really need to dig into `flexbox`!

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to use `flex`, **do not use `float`**, but `inline-block` alone and `vertical-align`:

```css
    #test {
      background: yellow;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    #block1 {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: grey;
      vertical-align:middle;
    }
    
    #block2 {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: green;
      vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="block1">
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
  </div><!--
  --><div id="block2">
    sample
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zjzyryae/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox for it

```
#test {
        background: yellow;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you using display flex for them all? it's a new trick and worth to try.
using flex from the beginning and change the type of your css code.

this is all what i can give u.

```css
    div#test {
        background: yellow;
        display: flex;
      flex-direction:row;
    }

div#block1, div#block2{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;}
    div#block1 {
        background-color: grey;
    }

    div#block2 {
        background-color: yellow;
      align-items:center;
      justify-content:center
    }
    div#inside-block2{
        background-color:green;
    }
```

```html
<div id="test">

    <div id="block1">
        <div>test</div>
        <div>test</div>
        <div>test</div>
        <div>test</div>
        <div>test</div>
        <div>test</div>
        <div>test</div>
        <div>test</div>
        <div>test</div>
        <div>test</div>  
    </div>

    <div id="block2">
      <div id="inside-block2">
        sample
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

so what i did is, made a wrap called test with a child block1 and block2, and a block2 id has a child which you can place or replace it wherever you want. you can learn more about flex in [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

for some my code tips. use `div#id` for calling an id name in css, i believe in some browser could a little bit jumpy if you only calling them using this `#id`.

wish it will help you.