# Right align unknown height div without flex?

Tags: html, css

To continue my question [Vertically center align divs with unknown height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807700/vertically-center-align-divs-with-unknown-height)

I have such code:

https://jsfiddle.net/yyjde1gb/

```css
#test {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
#block1 {
  background-color: grey;
}
#block2 {
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="block1">
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
  <div id="block2">
    sample
  </div>
</div>
```

It uses flex.

The question is: is it possible to get the same result without flex (and without JavaScript surely)?

IMPORTANT: It is forbidden to hard-code any heights or widths in pixels, ems, percent, ... (which makes the difficulty for this question). All the heights and widths are implicitely formed only by the contained text. That's an adaptive footer prototype.

First thing that comes to mind is to use floats - but it is impossible because of the `vertical-align: middle` of the "block2" div (floats are `vertical-align: top` only) - see details in [Vertically center align divs with unknown height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807700/vertically-center-align-divs-with-unknown-height) .

EDIT1: The "test" div is supposed to span to all the width of the page since it is a footer.

EDIT2: The proposed solution should support the oldest browsers possible.

UPDATE1: The best answer is by **@Muhammad Usman**. The pseudo-element `:after` is supported in older browsers that `transform` proposed by **@Nenad Vracar**'s answer. Thank you everybody!

UPDATE2: In the **@Muhammad Usman**'s answer it may be necessary to add `line-height` property - if it is declared in some parent block (thus affecting our footer). I had to add `line-height: 0;` to the zero-sized font block and `line-height: 16px;` to the block with 16px font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With following `HTML` we can make it possible in 3 steps.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child block1">
       // block one content goes here...
  </div>
  <div class="child block2">
       // block two content goes here...
  </div>
</div>
```

**Step #01:**

Use `display: inline-block` property to make child elements middle aligned.

```
.child {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**Step # 02:**

Remove the extra space added as a result of making elements `inline-block`. Here is one way of removing this space:

```
.parent {
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.child {
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

**Step #03:**

Make elements to touch the extreme corners. Here is a method that will align the left element to the left edge and right one to the right edge of browser (In case parent is occupying full browser width).

```
.parent {
  text-align: justify;
}
.parent:after {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
  height: 0;
}
```

You can see the demo in following snippet:

```css
.parent {
  background: yellow;
  text-align: justify;
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.parent:after {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
  height: 0;
}
.child {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.block1 {
  background-color: grey;
}
.block2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child block1">
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child block2">
    sample
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child block1">
    <div>test test test test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test test test test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test test test test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child block2">
    sample text goes here...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: relative` on parent and `position: absolute` on right element.

```css
#test {
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
#block1 {
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
}
#block2 {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="block1">
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
  <div id="block2">
    sample
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `display:inline-block;` on your child elements, and then use `vertical-align:`

```css
#test {
  background: yellow;
}
#block1 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
}
#block2 {
  background-color: green;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="block1">
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
  <div id="block2">
    sample
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that CSS tables would do the trick as shown below.

I enclosed the text in `#block2` in a `div`, which may be more consistent with the mark-up in `#block1`.

(Note: Panglos provided the same answer as this in the earlier version of your question. Am I missing something in your requirements?)

```css
#test {
  background: yellow;
  display: table;
}
#block1, #block2 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#block1 div {
  background-color: grey;
}
#block2 div {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="block1">
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
  <div id="block2">
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>sample text goes here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```