# How to vertically center images next to one another

Tags: html, css, image

I want the difference between tall and short images to not be as jarring as it is. Unfamiliar with coding jargon so forgive my ineptitude. Attached image describes change I want better[graph of what my site currently looks like and what I want it to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l360n.png). Images on my page are three per line, unseparated in the code, as shown below.

```
    <img src="so.jpg">
    <img src="ch.jpg">
    <img src="CC.jpg">
    <img src="blue.jpg">
    <img src="tv.jpg">
    <img src="do.jpg">
    <img src="bwire.jpg">
    <img src="nail.jpg">
    <img src="tom.jpg">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertically center align divs with unknown height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807700/vertically-center-align-divs-with-unknown-height)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#holder{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#image1,#image2,#image3 {
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
#image2{
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
    <div id="image1"></div>
    <div id="image2"></div>
    <div id="image3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vertically center images next to one another

```css
div{
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" height="150px" width="150">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" height="500px" width="500">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" height="300px" width="300">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a class in the parent wrapper image then give the class `display: flex` , `align-items: center`, `justify-content: center`

```css
.parent {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" height="200px" width="250">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" height="350px" width="250">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" height="200px" width="250">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.holder{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.img{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
}

.img2{
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="img img1">Image1</div>
  <div class="img img2">Image2</div>
  <div class="img img3">Image3</div>
</div>
```